# Как спарсить то что загружается аяксом

Tags: ajax

Есть страница https://vacations.ctrip.com/tours/d-bali-438#_flta на ней есть предложения по турам, с неё надо спарсить цену для каждого тура (скрин http://prntscr.com/nkg3ei цена это 2699), цена выводится через аякс, урл аякса если посмотреть через инструменты веб-разработчика следующий https://vacations.ctrip.com/tour-mainsite-vacations/api/product но там ничего нет. Как спарсить эти данные? Вариант заходить парсером по каждой ссылке и собирать данные таким образом не подходит, так как слишком долго.

Comment: разберитесь с API и пользуйтесь им. полчаса дожидаться загрузки страницы будет не быстрее...а потом еще парсить HTML....тут же вам чистые данные в виде json'а отдают...не вижу никакой проблемы

Comment: там с два десятка запросов к веб-сервису а не только один /api/product/

Comment: в продукте вы ничего не видите потому что он принимает только пост запросы и ожидает от вас ряд параметров

Comment: если их выслать он прекрасно возвращает все

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответы, не могу найти на этом сайте API вроде бы везде посмотрел.